# Symfony2 app/console error: Unrecognized options "doctrine"

Tags: symfony, elasticsearch

I've installed elasticsearch integration on symfony2.

I was following this tutorial:  http://richardmiller.co.uk/2011/11/11/symfony2-integrating-elasticsearch/

When I run this command:

```
php app/console fos:elastica:populate
```

I get this error:

```
[Symfony\Component\Config\Definition\Exception\InvalidConfigurationException]  
 Unrecognized options "doctrine" 
 under "fos_elastica.indexes.bookmarks.types.site"
```

What does this error mean and how do I fix it?

Comment: What's your ORM for your DB in Symonfy? Are you using Doctrine or maybe MongoDB?

Comment: As the blog, it use orm and doctrine like method

Comment: under your mapping did you define any `driver: orm`? Could you put your mapping here?

Comment: Yep in the config.yml, i've put this:

fos_elastica:  
    clients:
        default: { host: localhost, port: 9200 }
    indexes:
        bookmarks:
            client: default
            types:
                site:
                    mappings:
                        name:
                        keywords:
                    doctrine:
                        driver: orm
                        model: Alex\ElasticTestBundle\Entity\Site
                        provider:
                        listener:
                        finder:

Answer (score 1):

it's because "doctrine" is not recognized anymore.
You should now use "persistence" instead.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are getting the error because you have specified an unrecognised option "doctrine" in your FOS elasticsearch setting.

Your setting should look similar to the following:

```
fos_elastica:
    indexes:
        bookmarks:
            types:
                site:
                   mappings:
                       ...
                   persistence:
                       ...
                   _parent:
                       ...

                   doctrine <-- if you have this option on this level, it shouldn't be.
```

See https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSElasticaBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/types.md

Comment: Yes, but i'was thinking that it use doctrine for push data inside elastic search database. Entities orm with doctrine "use" should be used for this reason. As the blog says....

Comment: ONE MOMENT!
i think it'my error, it's not a blog error.... there is a true FOQElasticsearch bundle, i've installed FOSelasticsearchBundle...
I think FOQ makes an doctrine interpretation. now i install it and i try.

Comment: You should use FOSElasticaBundle instead of FOQElasticaBundle, because FOQElasticaBundle has now moved to FOSElasticaBundle.

Comment: Pls include your config file so I can see your settings. Pls redact to remove any sensitive data.